# Rounding down DECIMAL(14,3) to third decimal digit in SQL 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, operators

I have to round down all incoming data with type `DECIMAL(14,3)` which has 3 decimal digit to the last one. I.e.:

```
100; 100.0; 100.00; 100.000 -> 100
100.2; 100.02; 100.20; 100.22 -> 100.xx
```

but

```
100.221 -> 100.22
100.229 -> 100.22
```

Using which SQL operator can I check that residue of division in decimal digit is greater then zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx

See the section: Using Round to Truncate

Answer (score 4):

> Using which SQL operator can I check
>   that residue of division in decimal
>   digit is greater then zero?

I dont know exactly what you want to achieve with that but if you want a way to calculate the decimal residue, `%` (Modulo) is the way. It provides the integer remainder after dividing the first numeric expression by the second one. So, you can do this

1) `SELECT 100.229 % 1;`
   `GO`

gives `0.229` as result.

2) `SELECT (100.229 * 100) % 1;`
   `GO`

gives `0.900` as result. There you have the residue from decimal division.

But if you want to truncate, you can do as [David B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308259/rounding-down-decimal14-3-to-thrid-decimal-digit-in-sql-2008/1308295#1308295) suggested and use ROUND() to truncate:

> ```
> SELECT ROUND(100.221, 2, 1); 
> GO 
> SELECT ROUND(100.229, 2, 1); 
> GO
> ```