# Get only two decimal points in money datatype in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, rounding

```
SELECT ROUND(123.4567, 2)` gives me `123.4600`
```

But I need `123.46`.

Data type of field is money.

**Solution:**

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FieldName","{0:0.00}") %>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If applicable, format on the view layer, not on the data layer, i.e. read all the data and truncate it later (such as in C# client)

Comment: +1. Binding it like this in repeater worked `<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FieldName","{0:0.00}")%>`. Thanks for directing me to solve the actual problem.

Comment: @Ismail: Glad it helped! :) P.S. I had the same problems - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308259/rounding-down-decimal14-3-to-third-decimal-digit-in-sql-2008 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938296/remove-trailing-zeros-from-decimal-in-sql-server

Comment: But this would not work in edit components like EvExpress grid. Edit forms are broken by that.

Answer (score 24):

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(123.4567, 2) AS MONEY)
```

Will do what you are after

Comment: This works, but when I assign the value to a field in Repeater on my .aspx page, it again show two trailing zeros. I'm using Linq to sql.

Comment: You could use a ToString() in your repeater specifying the format to how you want it.

Comment: +1 thanks for your answer. Your answer is also right looking at my question. But @abatishchev tried to solve the bigger problem instead of just answering my question. That's why, I've accepted his answer.

Answer (score 4):

@IsmailS - To me, the larger picture is to let the data server format as much as possible, especially when it's something as simple as an inline cast.  It yields less clutter in your other code.  For example, casting ***Price***, a money field:

`select CAST(Price as numeric(17,2)) Price from PriceTable`

YMMV - It's my personal experience.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROUND(123.4567, 2,1)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003(SQL.90).aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT FORMAT(123.4567,'N2')
```

It will Help You Out